# Как исправить вывод некорректных символов в консоль g++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

> [Running] cd "c:\Users\I\Desktop\Новая папка\WHAT" && g++
> Untitled-1.cpp -o  Untitled-1 && "c:\Users\I\Desktop\Новая
> папка\WHAT"Untitled-1 "g++" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥� ��������,
> �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.
>
> [Done] exited with code=1 in 0.03 seconds

Comment: Напишите, где и чем Вы это запускаете?

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, у Вас кодовая страница, в которой работает консоль, не поддерживает русскую кодировку - откуда еще могут взяться эти странные значки.

Что, если вначале, до того, как вводить перечисленные команды, принудительно переключить кодировку вводом команды

```
    chcp 65001
```

Возможно, поможет!

После комментария о том, что "к сожалению, не помогло" я решил дополнить ответ.

Нужно проверить вот такой параметр в винде, он отвечает за отображение русских букв в том, что винда считает "не-юникод программами" (к котрым, замечу, относится и виндовая консоль):

[image: Куда ткнуть и что проверить]

Comment: К сожалению не помогло(

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все заработало.