# есть ли что-то типа encoding при вызове os.system

Tags: python, ос

при выполнении os.system вместо русских символов уходят кракозябры типа: �� 㤠���� ���樠����஢��� ���ன�⢮ PRN . как ввести русские символы, если они заменяются. пробовал команду через консоль - там все нормально.

[image: Ошибка]

язык для программ тоже русский
[image: lang]

Консольная команда
[image: вставка]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как исправить вывод некорректных символов в консоль g++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1320725/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-g)

Comment: Непонятно кто из кого вызывается, приведите код какой-то что ли. В консоли кодировка cp866, у питона родная кодировка utf-8.

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @aleksandr barakin лучше, но нет возможности.

Answer (score 1):

Да, перед выводом с os.system напишите:

```
os.system("chcp 65001 > nul")
```

Проблема возникает, из-за несовместимости стандартной кодировки консоли с кириллицей. Строка (которую я написал выше) изменит кодировку консоли на UTF-8