# Как задать кодировку UTF-8 для всех страниц ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

На всех страницах, где есть русские символы появляются иероглифы. Причина в кодировке. Как задать глобально кодировку в ASP .NET Core 5? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шаблон 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кодировка страниц в ASP.NET и так UTF-8, вопрос - что вы сделали, что она перестала ей быть. Задать кодировку можно в HTTP заголовке Content-Type или прописать meta тег в HTML.

Comment: @aepot создал пустой проект asp .net core, ничего не делал даже ещё :)

Comment: какой именно шаблон вы использовали для создания проекта? покажите код, который отдает ответ, с которого сделан скриншот. Отредактируйте пост.

Comment: Такое, может быть, если вы открыли файл проекта (например, любой `.cs`) через простой блокнот или нечто отличающееся от студии, а потом сохранили файл в другой кодировке.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не открывал

Comment: @aepot прикрепил

Comment: Ну, как вариант - кодировка настроена неправильно в самой винде? Гляньте вот эти вопрос-ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1320725/

Comment: @S.H. неа, не оно. :) Браузеру фиолетово на кодировки винды в целом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Пожалуйста прикладывайте код текстом, чтобы в следующий раз мне не пришлось перепечатывать его с картинки.*

Если в лоб решать проблему кодировки, то вот так.

```cs
app.Run(async context =>
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain;charset=utf-8";
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Привет!");
});
```

Смысл решения в том, что вы сообщаете браузеру явно с помощью HTTP заголовка `Content-Type`, что это в ответе просто текст, и какая у него кодировка.

Вообще пустой проект - это не практично, создайте MVC шаблон (например Web API) и пишите код в контроллере. Там не должно быть проблем с кодировками.

Желательно писать такие проекты под .NET 5 или 6, чтобы случайно не привыкнуть к устаревшим версиям ASP.NET.

Comment: Спасибо! Учту замечание